# Problem building my Xamarin Forms iOS application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

The error I'm getting is

/Users/paulwroe/Projects/Project/iOS/MTOUCH: Error MT2023: Binding Optimizer failed processing `System.Void AVFoundation.AVAssetImageGenerator::GenerateCGImagesAsynchronously(Foundation.NSValue[],AVFoundation.AVAssetImageGeneratorCompletionHandler)`. (MT2023) (Project.iOS)

Comment: Firstly ,make sure that the version of VS and Xcode are up to date. The element causing the issue is named in the error message. To fix this issue the assembly named (or containing the type or method named) will need to be provided in a bug report (https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/) along with a complete build log with verbosity enabled (i.e. -v -v -v -v in the Additional mtouch arguments)  .

Comment: Here is the extra information